# Typeorm createQueryBuilder.innnerJoinSelect() not returning the columns of a table

Tags: typeorm

I'm attempting to select columns of two tables tradie,postcode_distance using innerJoinAndSelect but unfortunately, I'm not fetching those columns.

Here's what I'm trying with typeorm createQueryBuilder()

```
this.createQueryBuilder('tradie')
  .innerJoin(
    'tradie.categories',
    'category',
    'category.category_id = :categoryId',
    {
      categoryId,
    },
  )
  .innerJoinAndSelect(
    'postcode_distance',
    'postcodeDistance',
    'postcodeDistance.source = ANY(tradie.directoryPostcodes)',
  )
  .where('tradie.plan IN (:...planIds)', { planIds })
  .andWhere('postcodeDistance.destination = :postcode', { postcode })
  .andWhere('postcodeDistance.driving_distance <= :radius', { radius })
  .andWhere('tradie.enable_spiral_search = TRUE')
  .andWhere('tradie.is_active = TRUE')
  .select('tradie')
```

Here's the SQL I'm expecting to be generated.

```
Select t.*,pd.*
FROM tradie t
INNER JOIN tradie_category tc 
ON t.tradie_id=tc.tradie_id
INNER JOIN Category c ON
c.category_id=tc.category_id
AND c.category_id=$1
INNER JOIN postcode_distance pd ON
pd.source=ANY(t.directory_postcodes) 
WHERE t.plan_id IN($2,$3)
AND pd.destination=$4 AND
pd.driving_distance<=$5 AND
t.enable_spiral_search=TRUE AND
t.is_active=TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like select() will reset the  selected columns above it. Removing select() fixed it